# Activating the menu working only after two clicks

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, blazor

I have a menu that when I click on something the menu becomes active and is highlighted.

The code works fine, I don't know if it's a problem in the blazor or it's something in my code anyway.

But what's happening is the following, when I open the application and I click once on some of the menus nothing happens, then if I click again the menu starts to work normally with just one click

**HTML Code:**

```
<div>
   <ul class="nav" onclick="ActiveTest()">
      <li>
         <a href="#" class="active">
         <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
         <span class="name">Home</span>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">
         <i class="fas fa-book-reader"></i>
         <span class="name">Reader</span>
         </a>
      </li>
      ...
   </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function ActiveTest() {
    $(".nav li a").click(function () {
        $(".nav li a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
}
```

Anyone who has had this problem can tell me a way to make this work without this two-click issue when the app is opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first click you are calling ActiveTest which then adds the click event to all the `<li>` in your code.

You probably want something like this instead.

HTML

```
<div class="bar">
   <ul class="nav">
      <li >
         <a href="#" onclick="OpenMenu(this)" class="active">
         <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
         <span class="name">Home</span>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#" onclick="OpenMenu(this)">
         <i class="fas fa-book-reader"></i>
         <span class="name">Reader</span>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
function OpenMenu(el) {
    
   $(".nav li a").removeClass("active"); 
   $(el).addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: I tested your methodology it seems that the double click part no longer exists, but when I click it now it disappears the highlight and no longer applies. Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/qk3jL0se/

Comment: See updated answer